# Change color of dynamically created anchor tag on click event

Tags: javascript, anchor

I am creating some anchor `<a>` tags on the fly with **Javascript**. 
Whenever any user clicks on one of these links I want the the background colour of the tag to change.

I am creating the `<a>` links on the fly like this:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = newstr;
var linktext = document.createTextNode(count);
link.appendChild(linktext);
```

I am getting all the links on the page by using:

```
document.onclick=function() {
    var a_array = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    console.log(a_array.length);
}
```

This gives me the total number of links but I want to know which element has been clicked. I have tried using the `this` keyword but did get the wanted indformation. I think I am using it wrong.

I ***do not*** want to use **jQuery**.

Any alternate code to target the currently clicked link will also help.

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, don't tag the question with jQuery!

Comment: This is very basic stuff that you could have found in any number of Javascript tutorials on the 'Net.  It’s probably also been asked and answered before here on Stack Overflow as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect `a` tag click using this:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    tags[i].onclick = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        return false;   
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qG7yr/)

Comment: This will absolutely not work. Have you even tried it?

Comment: This works on a collection? I think you need to loop

Comment: The OP is creating the links dynamically. What if he creates them after this declaration? See http://jsfiddle.net/f7t7m/

Answer (score 3):

You seem to try using [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) (assigning the click handler on document level). In that case you need to know where the click originated. `event` is your friend here:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    e = e || event;
    var from = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (/a/i.test(from.tagName)) {
        from.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

<strike>The jQuery way of delegating would be</strike>: removed, OP needs no jQuery. He/she [may be right](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Here's a j[**sFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/er4dm/) with a bit more code do demonstrate the usefulness of event delegation

Comment: $(".active").removeClass("active"): $(this).addClass("active") is likely a better fit

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the jQuery tag on your post, an alternate solution that may work is:

JS:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
   $(this).css('background','red');
});
```

Comment: Next reset all the others too :)

Comment: The OP is creating the links dynamically. What if he creates them after this declaration?

Comment: @KooiInc, good point, I've edited my answer to delegate off the body tag

Answer (score 0):

If the op creates the links dynamically, ie:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
```

Then all he needs to do is set the link handler at that point:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.onclick = function()
{
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  return false; //stop the click from navigating somewhere.
}
a.href = newstr;
```

Which will add the same handler to all dynamically created links - right where he creates them.

It's a matter of which links he needs to recognize - if it's all links, then he might have to getElementsByTagName, as well as the code above for dynamic links.